# Update pod configuration for running pod

Tags: kubernetes

I would like to update image version for my running kubernetes pod.

My current config is:

```
spec:
  containers:
    - name: ADMIN_USER
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          key: jenkins-admin-user
          name: jenkins
    image: jenkins/jenkins:latest
```

I would like to update it to

```
spec:
  containers:
    - name: ADMIN_USER
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          key: jenkins-admin-user
          name: jenkins
    image: jenkins/jenkins:2.247
```

I have tried to run an apply as I understood by reading documentation `kubectl apply -f jenkins.yaml --namespace=infrastructure`, but nothing changed (nor my pod was restarted automatically).

Can someone advice how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `replace`

`kubectl replace -f jenkins.yaml --namespace=infrastructure`

Comment: Is this the same as editing the deployment? I am trying to solve it by editing the deployment.

Comment: well if you edit the yaml file locally and want update the remote  deployment then you should use replace.

Comment: @Boban you can edit directly on deployment using ```kubectl edit deployment <yourdeployname>```

Comment: Thanks! I was actually able to edit the deployment and it updated the pod. Now I just need to try to solve the jenkins pod problems :)

Comment: ok cool. maybe create another question I will have a look on that

Comment: I have created a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64026943/jenkins-unable-to-initialize-using-kubernetes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221932/discussion-between-boban-and-dashrath-mundkar).

Answer (score 0):

Probably image: `jenkins/jenkins:2.247` is the same as image: `jenkins/jenkins:latest` and because of that, no update occurred.

Tip: Try to not use latest tag but to set the specific tag always.