# Jenkins unable to initialize using Kubernetes

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline

From yesterday I started having problems with jenkins pod - it is unable to be initialized. I haven't update any configuration in the meantime.

This is how my pod deployment configuration looks like

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  annotations:
    checksum/config: eed56a3d795865e4432dea721435a777ee100059998724f0d57bf1f9378dbb88
  creationTimestamp: 2020-09-17T14:14:12Z
  generateName: jenkins-74cc957b47-
  labels:
    app: jenkins
    chart: jenkins-0.35.0
    component: jenkins-jenkins-master
    heritage: Tiller
    pod-template-hash: "3077513603"
    release: jenkins
  name: jenkins-74cc957b47-zf67f
  namespace: infrastructure
  ownerReferences:
  - apiVersion: apps/v1
    blockOwnerDeletion: true
    controller: true
    kind: ReplicaSet
    name: jenkins-74cc957b47
    uid: 77b5d3d7-f0f1-11ea-acd2-02be15828c0e
  resourceVersion: "158370354"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/infrastructure/pods/jenkins-74cc957b47-zf67f
  uid: 0fcefd0d-f8f0-11ea-acd2-02be15828c0e
spec:
  containers:
  - args:
    - --argumentsRealm.passwd.$(ADMIN_USER)=$(ADMIN_PASSWORD)
    - --argumentsRealm.roles.$(ADMIN_USER)=admin
    env:
    - name: JAVA_OPTS
    - name: JENKINS_OPTS
    - name: JENKINS_SLAVE_AGENT_PORT
      value: "50000"
    - name: ADMIN_PASSWORD
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          key: jenkins-admin-password
          name: jenkins
    - name: ADMIN_USER
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          key: jenkins-admin-user
          name: jenkins
    image: jenkins/jenkins:2.247
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    livenessProbe:
      failureThreshold: 12
      httpGet:
        path: /login
        port: http
        scheme: HTTP
      initialDelaySeconds: 90
      periodSeconds: 10
      successThreshold: 1
      timeoutSeconds: 5
    name: jenkins
    ports:
    - containerPort: 8080
      name: http
      protocol: TCP
    - containerPort: 50000
      name: slavelistener
      protocol: TCP
    readinessProbe:
      failureThreshold: 3
      httpGet:
        path: /login
        port: http
        scheme: HTTP
      initialDelaySeconds: 60
      periodSeconds: 10
      successThreshold: 1
      timeoutSeconds: 1
    resources:
      limits:
        cpu: "1280m"
        memory: 3Gi
      requests:
        cpu: 50m
        memory: 256Mi
    terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
    terminationMessagePolicy: File
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /var/jenkins_home
      name: jenkins-home
    - mountPath: /var/jenkins_config
      name: jenkins-config
      readOnly: true
    - mountPath: /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins/
      name: plugin-dir
    - mountPath: /usr/share/jenkins/ref/secrets/
      name: secrets-dir
    - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
      name: default-token-5tbbb
      readOnly: true
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  initContainers:
  - command:
    - sh
    - /var/jenkins_config/apply_config.sh
    env:
    - name: ADMIN_PASSWORD
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          key: jenkins-admin-password
          name: jenkins
    - name: ADMIN_USER
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          key: jenkins-admin-user
          name: jenkins
    image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    name: copy-default-config
    resources:
      limits:
        cpu: "1280m"
        memory: 3Gi
      requests:
        cpu: 50m
        memory: 256Mi
    terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
    terminationMessagePolicy: File
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /var/jenkins_home
      name: jenkins-home
    - mountPath: /var/jenkins_config
      name: jenkins-config
    - mountPath: /var/jenkins_plugins
      name: plugin-dir
    - mountPath: /usr/share/jenkins/ref/secrets/
      name: secrets-dir
    - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
      name: default-token-5tbbb
      readOnly: true
  nodeName: ip-172-20-62-226.eu-west-1.compute.internal
  priority: 0
  restartPolicy: Always
  schedulerName: default-scheduler
  securityContext:
    runAsUser: 0
  serviceAccount: default
  serviceAccountName: default
  terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
  tolerations:
  - effect: NoExecute
    key: node.kubernetes.io/not-ready
    operator: Exists
    tolerationSeconds: 300
  - effect: NoExecute
    key: node.kubernetes.io/unreachable
    operator: Exists
    tolerationSeconds: 300
  volumes:
  - configMap:
      defaultMode: 420
      name: jenkins
    name: jenkins-config
  - emptyDir: {}
    name: plugin-dir
  - emptyDir: {}
    name: secrets-dir
  - name: jenkins-home
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: jenkins
  - name: default-token-5tbbb
    secret:
      defaultMode: 420
      secretName: default-token-5tbbb
status:
  conditions:
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: 2020-09-17T14:15:03Z
    status: "True"
    type: Initialized
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: 2020-09-17T14:17:11Z
    status: "True"
    type: Ready
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: null
    status: "True"
    type: ContainersReady
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: 2020-09-17T14:14:12Z
    status: "True"
    type: PodScheduled
  containerStatuses:
  - containerID: docker://688f4ad7dde842c2b5d6a0f1fd3cdd7ca156c8457336ca07f1d11270c2df0779
    image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
    imageID: docker-pullable://jenkins/jenkins@sha256:a3e7b2b6efbc2c252608b028bb844e419d44ad5e3974770c4543ab7ae6e8eb27
    lastState: {}
    name: jenkins
    ready: true
    restartCount: 0
    state:
      running:
        startedAt: 2020-09-17T14:15:05Z
  hostIP: 172.20.62.226
  initContainerStatuses:
  - containerID: docker://6761eab1b990aa42c7ec21ee84d1e2362eeddf9373f595ccb13b0e59c0462505
    image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
    imageID: docker-pullable://jenkins/jenkins@sha256:a3e7b2b6efbc2c252608b028bb844e419d44ad5e3974770c4543ab7ae6e8eb27
    lastState: {}
    name: copy-default-config
    ready: true
    restartCount: 0
    state:
      terminated:
        containerID: docker://6761eab1b990aa42c7ec21ee84d1e2362eeddf9373f595ccb13b0e59c0462505
        exitCode: 0
        finishedAt: 2020-09-17T14:15:02Z
        reason: Completed
        startedAt: 2020-09-17T14:14:41Z
  phase: Running
  podIP: 100.105.185.69
  qosClass: Burstable
  startTime: 2020-09-17T14:14:12Z
```

I have tried to edit it and set the specific jenkins image version, for example `image: jenkins/jenkins:2.219`, but it is still not able to initialize.

When I run `kubectl logs jenkins-df87c46d5-52dtt -c copy-default-config -n infrastructure` I can see the following log:

```
11:21:05 Failed in the last attempt (curl -sSfL --connect-timeout 20 --retry 3 --retry-delay 0 --retry-max-time 60 https://updates.jenkins.io/dynamic-2.248//latest/workflow-cps.hpi -o /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins/workflow-cps.jpi)
Downloading plugin: workflow-cps-plugin from https://updates.jenkins.io/dynamic-2.248//latest/workflow-cps-plugin.hpi
curl: (28) Resolving timed out after 20527 milliseconds
11:21:05 Failure (28) Retrying in 1 seconds...
curl: (28) Resolving timed out after 20526 milliseconds
11:21:08 Failure (28) Retrying in 1 seconds...
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
11:21:14 Failure (22) Retrying in 1 seconds...
```

Full output is available here: https://justpaste.it/8h30t

Answer (score 1):

Try this. I have removed the plugin directiory which might cause the issue

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  annotations:
    checksum/config: eed56a3d795865e4432dea721435a777ee100059998724f0d57bf1f9378dbb88
  creationTimestamp: 2020-09-17T14:14:12Z
  generateName: jenkins-74cc957b47-
  labels:
    app: jenkins
    chart: jenkins-0.35.0
    component: jenkins-jenkins-master
    heritage: Tiller
    pod-template-hash: "3077513603"
    release: jenkins
  name: jenkins-74cc957b47-zf67f
  namespace: infrastructure
  ownerReferences:
  - apiVersion: apps/v1
    blockOwnerDeletion: true
    controller: true
    kind: ReplicaSet
    name: jenkins-74cc957b47
    uid: 77b5d3d7-f0f1-11ea-acd2-02be15828c0e
  resourceVersion: "158370354"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/infrastructure/pods/jenkins-74cc957b47-zf67f
  uid: 0fcefd0d-f8f0-11ea-acd2-02be15828c0e
spec:
  containers:
  - args:
    - --argumentsRealm.passwd.$(ADMIN_USER)=$(ADMIN_PASSWORD)
    - --argumentsRealm.roles.$(ADMIN_USER)=admin
    env:
    - name: JAVA_OPTS
    - name: JENKINS_OPTS
    - name: JENKINS_SLAVE_AGENT_PORT
      value: "50000"
    - name: ADMIN_PASSWORD
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          key: jenkins-admin-password
          name: jenkins
    - name: ADMIN_USER
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          key: jenkins-admin-user
          name: jenkins
    image: jenkins/jenkins:2.247
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    livenessProbe:
      failureThreshold: 12
      httpGet:
        path: /login
        port: http
        scheme: HTTP
      initialDelaySeconds: 90
      periodSeconds: 10
      successThreshold: 1
      timeoutSeconds: 5
    name: jenkins
    ports:
    - containerPort: 8080
      name: http
      protocol: TCP
    - containerPort: 50000
      name: slavelistener
      protocol: TCP
    readinessProbe:
      failureThreshold: 3
      httpGet:
        path: /login
        port: http
        scheme: HTTP
      initialDelaySeconds: 60
      periodSeconds: 10
      successThreshold: 1
      timeoutSeconds: 1
    resources:
      limits:
        cpu: "1280m"
        memory: 3Gi
      requests:
        cpu: 50m
        memory: 256Mi
    terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
    terminationMessagePolicy: File
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /var/jenkins_home
      name: jenkins-home
    - mountPath: /var/jenkins_config
      name: jenkins-config
      readOnly: true
    - mountPath: /usr/share/jenkins/ref/secrets/
      name: secrets-dir
    - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
      name: default-token-5tbbb
      readOnly: true
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  initContainers:
  - command:
    - sh
    - /var/jenkins_config/apply_config.sh
    env:
    - name: ADMIN_PASSWORD
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          key: jenkins-admin-password
          name: jenkins
    - name: ADMIN_USER
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          key: jenkins-admin-user
          name: jenkins
    image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    name: copy-default-config
    resources:
      limits:
        cpu: "1280m"
        memory: 3Gi
      requests:
        cpu: 50m
        memory: 256Mi
    terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
    terminationMessagePolicy: File
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /var/jenkins_home
      name: jenkins-home
    - mountPath: /var/jenkins_config
      name: jenkins-config
    - mountPath: /usr/share/jenkins/ref/secrets/
      name: secrets-dir
    - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
      name: default-token-5tbbb
      readOnly: true
  nodeName: ip-172-20-62-226.eu-west-1.compute.internal
  priority: 0
  restartPolicy: Always
  schedulerName: default-scheduler
  securityContext:
    runAsUser: 0
  serviceAccount: default
  serviceAccountName: default
  terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
  tolerations:
  - effect: NoExecute
    key: node.kubernetes.io/not-ready
    operator: Exists
    tolerationSeconds: 300
  - effect: NoExecute
    key: node.kubernetes.io/unreachable
    operator: Exists
    tolerationSeconds: 300
  volumes:
  - configMap:
      defaultMode: 420
      name: jenkins
    name: jenkins-config
  - emptyDir: {}
    name: secrets-dir
  - name: jenkins-home
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: jenkins
  - name: default-token-5tbbb
    secret:
      defaultMode: 420
      secretName: default-token-5tbbb
```